# Is there a way to break out of the default_scope when using has_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tree, scope, has-many, default-scope

I have a tree-like model where in **all situations but one**, I want to scope the results to only return the roots.

```
class Licence < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :conditions => { :parent_licence_id, nil }

  belongs_to :parent_licence, :class_name => 'Licence'
  has_many :nested_licences, :class_name => 'Licence',
           :foreign_key => 'parent_licence_id', :dependent => :destroy
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :licences
end
```

Using `default_scope` seemed like an awesome idea because the various models which have associations to Licence (there are about 4 of them) and also any code using find(), would not need to do anything special.  The reason it *isn't* an awesome idea is that the default scope also applies to the `has_many`, which results in never finding the children.  But the `has_many` is the *only* place which needs to bust out of the scope, so as far as "default" behaviour goes, I think this `default_scope` is quite reasonable.

So is there some good way to get around this specific problem?

Here is one which I am not too fond of because it uses SQL for a nearly trivial query:

```
has_many :nested_licences, :class_name => 'Licence', :dependent => :destroy,
  :finder_sql => 'SELECT l.* FROM licences l WHERE l.parent_licence_id = #{id}',
  :counter_sql => 'SELECT COUNT(l.*) FROM licences l WHERE l.parent_licence_id = #{id}'
```

Alternatively is there some way to apply a named scope to an association from the model?  e.g. something along the lines of this nonsense-code:

```
class Licence < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :roots, :conditions => { :parent_licence_id, nil }

  belongs_to :parent_licence, :class_name => 'Licence'
  has_many :nested_licences, :class_name => 'Licence',
           :foreign_key => 'parent_licence_id', :dependent => :destroy
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :licences, :scope => :roots   # a :scope option doesn't really exist
end
```

I know I can also do this:

```
class Licence < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :roots, :conditions => { :parent_licence_id, nil }

  belongs_to :parent_licence, :class_name => 'Licence'
  has_many :nested_licences, :class_name => 'Licence',
           :foreign_key => 'parent_licence_id', :dependent => :destroy
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :licences, :conditions => { :parent_licence_id, nil }
end
```

But that really isn't very DRY.  Actually having to do every single query through `Licence.roots.find()` instead of `Licence.find()` isn't very DRY either, to be honest.  It's just asking for a bug to occur where the scope isn't used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Licence.unscoped.find()`

btw - 
The documentation for `ActiveRecord::Base.unscoped` says that chaining `unscoped` with a named `scope` method has no effect.
It is recommended to use the block form of `unscoped` because chaining `unscoped` with a named `scope` does not work. If "sent" (below) is a named_scope the following two statements are the same.

```
Message.unscoped.sent
Message.sent
```

fyi rails 2 also has `with_exclusive_scope` which can be helpful.

Comment: I also recommend not using conditions with default scope.  Just use default_scope for ordering.  When there are conditions, use a named scope.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you make use of the `:conditions` option on the association? Something like this:

```
has_many :nested_licences, :class_name => 'Licence',
         :dependent => :destroy, :conditions => "parent_licence_id = #{id}"
```

Comment: I tried that too, because the rdoc implied that it wouldn't be scoped (it said it would scope it if it was a hash, I assumed that meant the converse but it didn't.)  However, it was scoped after all. :-(